# How to parse a string containing a string and 5 integers without vectors c++

Tags: class, c++11

I am in the process of creating a functions that takes in a string as data that looks something like: "D. Smith, 87, 65, 98, 87, 92", and then parses the string at the commas and assigns the values to the variables: string name, int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, and int score5. Note that when the string is parsed, the first part of the string (D. Smith) should be saved as a string while the following parts (87, 65, 98, 87, 92) should be saved as ints. After taking the string as an input, the output should look like:

```
Name: D. Smith

Score One: 87

Score Two: 65

Score Three: 98

Score Four 87

Score Five: 92
```

I know that this can potentially be done with vectors, but my goal is to figure out a way to do without. Right now, this is the code I have:

```
Quarterback::Quarterback(string data) {

    string Name;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

        if (data[i] == ',')
            j++;
            while (j < 1){
                Name = Name + data[i];
            }

        .....
    }
```

Am I on the correct track with this thinking? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Before giving you a solution I will give you some hints so that you can think a bit more. Think of all parts where you need to split the string. Is the `,`, right? So, just check for comma as you did, and if you find it, you either found the string, or some of the integers that follow. In the other case, just add the character to some temporary string, which will be the current part you are parsing.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, (since you're using standard library) you should really make use of iterators. With them, you can "mark" any position in the string (and get it's char value), so no memory is wasted on temporary strings and you can have as many of them as you please (start of name, end of name, start of number, end of number, end of string, etc.). They of course support arithmetics (add/subtract, increment/decrement, compare, etc.). And a pair of iterators can be easily converted to string.

**Secondly**, you should use as many of built-in functions as possible (e.g. `std::find(...)` to find commas, pair of iterators to string conversion, etc.) to minimize possible bugs.

**Last** (but not least): divide a complex task into series of simple sub-tasks (with C++, they come at zero performance cost). In your case it would be: find next comma, parse number. So, your code should look similar to:

```
Quarterback::Quarterback(string data) {
    auto stringStart = data.cbegin();
    auto stringEnd = data.cend();

    auto nameStart = stringStart;
    auto nameEnd = findNextComma(nameStart, stringEnd);

    std::string name(nameStart, nameEnd); // easy as that :)

    auto numberStart = nameEnd;
    while (numberStart < stringEnd) {
        auto numberEnd = findNextComma(numberStart + 2, stringEnd); // skip previous comma and space
        int number = parseNumber(numberStart, numberEnd); // do whatever you need to do with an int
        numberStart = numberEnd;
    }
}

template <typename I> I findNextComma(I start, I end) {
    ...
}
template <typename I> int parseNumber(I start, I end) {
    ...
}
```